# Bar chart with multi series in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, bar-chart

I try to make a bar chart which gets loaded dynamically. It should shows more than one series for each entry on xAxis.
As an example the list bellow is one possible `entry`:

```
[AUF_1426597200377_183, Function 19, 1.0, NotSet, ORA_1425938965827_176,  Organizational unit 3, Computer-based appl. component 1, RechAnwendungsbaustein, hasType, Green, Computer-based appl. component 2, RechAnwendungsbaustein, hasType, Green,Computer-based appl. component 5, RechAnwendungsbaustein, hasType, yellow,]
```

It has one yellow and two Green. I need to create 3 bars, two of them of same colour. If the value is Green, then the number is 2, and if the value is yellow, the number is 1 as you can see in code. The value for xAxis is `second element in list`. But this code gives me not all the entries with length of greater than 10. And it makes the bars only for two entry, although I have 4 entry with the length of grater than 10.

```
      public void setfunctionalredundant() {
      XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
       XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
       int green;
       int yellow;
       for(List<String> entry : dc.getFuncTypeOrg().values()){
        if(ent.size()>10){
            green = Collections.frequency(ent, "Green");
            yellow = Collections.frequency(ent, "yellow");
            for(int j = 0 ; j<green;j++){
                series.getData().add(
                        new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(ent.get(1),2));
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<yellow;k++){
                series2.getData().add(
                        new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(ent.get(1),1));
            }

            }
        barchart.getData().addAll(series,series2);
        barchart.setBarGap(3);
        barchart.setCategoryGap(20);

    }

}
```